# How to execute the given code when I open a new tab on chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just wanted to execute

```js
document.querySelector("body > ntp-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#logo").singleColored = false
```

whenever I open a new tab. Just make google-logo colorful. Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: Get the [New Tab URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-new-tab-url/mmjbdbjnoablegbkcklggeknkfcjkjia?hl=en) extension and set it to use a local page which contains your script.

Comment: but it loads a new page. I only want to execute the above snippet when the new page opens in a chrome preferably via an extension. Is it possible?

Comment: "Whenever I open a new tab" is exactly what the extension is for. If you want to run a script whenever any *page*  opens, you'll have to write your own extension.